# Visual Studio setup project install prerequisites first

Tags: installshield, setup-project

I've created a VSTO PowerPoint add-in in Visual Studio. To distribute this to the users I have created an InstallShield setup project.

After building this project the installation and the add-in work fine if I use the option to download the prerequisites from the Internet.

However, when I use the option to extract the prerequisites from the Setup.exe, it doesn't work: the add-in itself is installed, but the prerequisites aren't.
I know that the prerequisites are included in the setup because without them the Setup.exe is around 2MB, with prereqs it's about 290MB.

I have the two necessary prerequisites selected in the Prerequisites view:
[image: Setup project prerequisites view screenshot]

In the Releases view, under the Setup.exe-tab of SingleImage, the "InstallShield Prerequisites Location" is also set to "**Extract from Setup.exe**".

But the installer just won't install the .NET Framework 4.5 (if necessary, is usually present on the user's systems), and the VSTO Runtime even though I've included it in the setup file!

Any help is much appreciated.

Comment: I'd suggest contacting InstallShield developers/specialists because the issue is related to their product.

Comment: Were you able to fix this? I am facing same issue with version 0.9.3 for VS2019